# Qual a diferença entre criar um módulo normalmente e criar um módulo dentro de uma função?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estive olhando alguns projetos de exemplo em AngularJS e me deparei várias vezes com o seguinte código:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('meuModulo', [
        'alguma.dependencia',
        'outra.dependencia'  
    ]);
})();
```

Este mesmo código, no padrão que estou acostumado, seria:

```
angular.module('meuModulo', [
    'alguma.dependencia',
        'outra.dependencia'  
    ]);
```

Ou seja, o código foi colocado dentro de uma `function`.

Há alguma diferença entre o primeiro e o segundo exemplo? Se sim, quais são as vantagens de se usar a primeira abordagem ao invés da segunda?

---

<sub>O código acima é apenas um exemplo de uma criação de um módulo em AngularJS.</sub>

Comment: [Modularização em JavaScript](http://tableless.com.br/modularizacao-em-javascript/)

Comment: Isso é um encapsulamento autoexecutado. Eu responderia, mas não tenho conhecimento de Angular para afirmas uma resposta.

Comment: Esta função tem a propriedade de fazer um autoload `(funcion(){  ... })()`, ou seja, ele autoexecuta o que está dentro.

Comment: Obrigado pelo link @GuilhermeLautert

Comment: Quando você encapsula, significa que os elementos dentro do módulo, serão autoexecutados... como get, http, etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O trecho 1 contém uma função de Função Imediatamente Invocada ou *Immediately-Invoked Function Expression* (IIFE).

Envolver seus componentes AngularJS numa expressão na forma de função imediatamente chamada ajuda a evitar que variáveis ​​e declarações de funções vivam mais tempo do que o esperado no escopo global, o que também ajuda a evitar colisões variáveis.

Isso se torna ainda mais importante quando o código está reduzido e empacotado em um único arquivo para implantação em um servidor de produção, fornecendo o escopo de variáveis ​​para cada arquivo.

Referencia: [AngularJS Guidelines](http://www.codestyle.co/Guidelines/angularjs)

Tem um artigo bem bacana em português sobre estas funções: [JavaScript IIFE](http://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/javascript/javascript-iife-conteiner-de-codigos/)

Answer (score 4):

A diferença dos dois códigos tem a ver com o tipo de escopo de variável implementado em JavaScript. JavaScript utiliza um [escopo de função](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx), ao invés do escopo em bloco utilizado por linguagens como `C` e `Java`.

Encapsulando a criação de *modules* dentro de uma função anônima faz com que todas as variáveis criadas dentro da função **não** sejam acessíveis fora da função.

Exemplo básico:

```js
(function() {
    var variavelLocal = 12;
    document.write(variavelLocal);
})();

document.write(variavelLocal);
```

Perceba que o código acima exibe o valor `12` apenas uma vez, o `document.write` de dentro da função anônima. O segundo `document.write` lança uma excecão, se você abrir o console do seu navegador vai ver o erro:

```
stacksnippets.net/js:18 Uncaught ReferenceError: variavelLocal is not defined
```

Quanto ao seu exemplo específico, não faz diferença alguma, visto que nenhuma variável é criada, então o escopo não importa nesse caso.

Answer (score 4):

O primeiro formato isola a função de variáveis declaradas no escopo global. Assim, todas as variáveis declaradas dentro da função ficam restringidas ao escopo desta, não influenciando o escopo global.

Answer (score 2):

Isto é uma IIFE Expressão de Função Imediatamente Invocada ou Immediately-Invoked Function Expression, ela é como se fosse um "modulo" autoexecutável que encapsula o código evitando colisões no escopo global.

Ela também evita colisões de variáveis no escopo global caso o codigo venha a ser minificado em um único arquivo.

Está é uma pratica difundida na comunidade angular pelo famoso Style Guide do John Papa. Recomendo você dar uma olhada pois existem muitas dicas legais de boas praticas para Angular 1 e 2 -> [John Papa's Angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/i18n/pt-BR.md#iife)